# Generate a oAuthConsent for a simple app which will never hit production?

Tags: java, google-api, google-oauth

I have written simple java application for my own use, which scans an Excel document and extracts some events from it. For the next stage I want it to sign in to my google account and create those events using the Google Calendar API.

I have already created a project in Google API Console. When I want to now create the "Other" oAuthClientID credential. To do that I have to generate the consent. But for consent I have to provide a product home page logo etc. But I dont have such stuff. Its just one app I created for my own use, so that i dont have to manually create 100 events a day. How should I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Home Page and logo should not be required.   If they are you should be able to just put anything in there it shouldn't matter.

If you are only going to be inserting these into your own calendar you should consider using a service account it will be much easier.  Just add the service account email address as a user and it will be able to insert into that calendar

Googles [Service account java tutorial](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount)

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a spin and report back.

Comment: Do Service Accounts work for "installed" applications i.e. thick clients

Comment: Service accounts work on anytime of application.   Try reading this it will get you up to speed http://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-service-account/